# containable on hasMany relationship

Tags: php, cakephp, contains

Greetings,

I am trying to tear down query returned from find call using containable in CakePHP.

for example I have 2 models, User and Post. User hasMany Post.

Now when I am using containable on find call like so:

```
$User->id = 1;
$User->find('first', array(
    'fields' => array('id'),
    'contain' => array('Post')
))
```

It will not return the associated Post, instead will just return the id of the user.

It works however if I am trying to fetch the data the other way around.
i.e this works:

```
   $Post->find('first', array(
        'fields' => array('id', 'user_id'),
        'conditions' => array('Post.user_id' => 1),
        'contain' => array('User')
    ))
```

this doesn't:

```
   $Post->find('first', array(
        'fields' => array('id'),
        'conditions' => array('Post.user_id' => 1),
        'contain' => array('User')
    ))
```

From the returned values I then suppose that for the containable to works, the foreignKey has to be in the fields.

How then would I be able to filter out the User fields on the first call as the association of user is stored in Post.user_id?

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank's.

-aw

Comment: Does Post belongTo User?  Maybe you need to define the relationships in both directions for everything to work.

Comment: @deceze I've tried setting recursive to 9999 (I know 2 is sufficient, but humor me). But it doesn't give me the associated post, It does work if I don't put the fields specification up there.

i. e find('all', array('contain' => 'Post')). 

but I need to actually filter out User's fields.

Comment: Can you post the code demonstrating how you defined your User model's $hasMany array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As larryb82 said you'll need to define the relationship in both directions in order to retrieve Posts data from the User model

A user has many posts.
A post belongs to an user

[CakePHP Doc example](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany)